Code executed inside a foreground service: one into main thread and one into a different thread
I am basically trying to understand on which threads my code is running.
In theory it should all run in the foreground group since the code is inside a Service started in the foreground.
Let's say I have the following classes:
public class Test {

    private Runnable runnable;
    private final Handler handler;


    public Test()
    {
        this.random = new Random();
        this.handler = new Handler();
    }


    private Runnable getRunnable(final String gpsCoordinates)
    {
        return new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Current Thread Test: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                System.out.println("Current Looper Test: "+ Looper.myLooper());
                handler.postDelayed(this, INTERVAL_MILLIS);
                if(condition)
                    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
            }
        };
    }

    public void test(final String gpsCoordinates)
    {
        runnable = getRunnable(gpsCoordinates);
        handler.postDelayed(runnable,  DELAY_MILLIS);
    }
}


public class FooThread extends Thread {

    private Test test;
    ...

    public FooThread(Test test)
    {
        this.test = test;
    }


    @Override
    public void run()
    {
            test.test();
            //other stuff
            System.out.println("Current Thread FooThread: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            System.out.println("Current Looper FooThread: "+ Looper.myLooper());
    }

}

As you can see I have a Test class that execute some code at some interval until a condition is met and a class FooThread which call Test.test other than doing other stuff.
Inside my service I simply run:
new FooThread(new Test()).start();

To my surprise this is what I get:
Current Thread FooThread: Thread-3
Current Looper FooThread: null

Current Thread Test: main
Current Looper Test: Looper (main, tid 2) {3c367e9}

Could someone explain to me why test.test() is on the main thread since the code it's inside a runnable?
Also, I can check that Thread-3 is indeed a Thread in the foreground group and not in the background group? Generally, threads in the foreground group get about 95% of the total execution time from the device, while the background group gets roughly 5%.
Thank you.


Could someone explain to me why test.test() is on the main thread since the code it's inside a runnable?

Because that's where you initialized it.
You said:

> Inside my service I simply run:

new FooThread(new Test()).start();


So ...

You're in a service, so you start on the main thread.
You create a new Test(), which is created on the main thread.
Test constructor creates new Handler(), which again is created on the main thread.
You start() the Thread, which spawns Thread-3
Thread-3 sends a delayed message to Handler() which will run on the main thread it was created on.
The Thread runnable prints that it's on the Thread-3 thread that it spawned, as expected.
Your delayed handler - which is running on the main thread - eventually prints that it's on the main thread, as expected.

The fact that the handler is using a Runnable is irrelevant. A Runnable is just an interface for "something that can run" - it does not have to be a thread. A Thread is a Runnable - a Runnable is not a Thread.

Also, I can check that Thread-3 is indeed a Thread in the foreground group and not in the background group?

Is that a question or comment? Yes, you can get a Thread priority.
EDIT: move new Test() to inside the Thread run method to see the difference.
